# Log configurations in my Java application

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, jsonpath

I'm using a library called `JSONPath` to parse JSON messages in Java. I should always add the following code to make its redundent logs to disappear.

Is there any ways to do this in the log4j `.xml` file or somewhere other than my code itself? I just don't want to see this inside the technical code.

```
// must be added for the JSONPath debug logs to disappear.
LoggerContext logContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger log = logContext.getLogger("com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath");
log.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Comment: Try adding this to the xml file `
<logger name="com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Tried adding that to `log4j2.xml` file. But got error: `2019-04-19 16:03:26,965 main WARN Error while converting string [] to type [class org.apache.logging.log4j.Level]. Using default value [null]. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown level constant [].`

Comment: My bad! that's for `log4j`. For `log4j2`it should be `<logger name="com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath" level="info"> </logger>`.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz no change. Remember, this `logger` comes from `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` if you see my code. I hope this helps.